# MPMusicPlayerController and AVSpeechSynthesizer trying to implement ducking

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller, avspeechsynthesizer

I am using the MPMusicPlayerController and AVSpeechSynthesizer classes for the first time in an app. It's a running app that plays music (using MPMusicPlayerController) and updates the runner with stats every 5 minutes (using AVSpeechSynthesizer). It works fine but the music and broadcast are at the same volume so depending on the song playing it can be difficult to hear the stats, so now I want the music volume to lower while the stats are being broadcasting. The code below works only to reduce the music volume when the stats begin broadcasting but it doesn't resume the music after the stats broadcast is concluded, which is of course what I want it to do. I am using this solution from this post [Setting iOS MPMusicPlayerController volume relative to AVAudioPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055234/setting-ios-mpmusicplayercontroller-volume-relative-to-avaudioplayer/19218878#19218878).
My code is below:

```
- (void)setAudioSessionWithDucking:(BOOL)isDucking
    {
    AudioSessionSetActive(NO);

    UInt32 overrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker = 1;
    AudioSessionSetProperty     (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof     (overrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker), &overrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker);

    UInt32 overrideCategoryMixWithOthers = 1;
    AudioSessionSetProperty     (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof     (overrideCategoryMixWithOthers), &overrideCategoryMixWithOthers);

    UInt32 value = isDucking;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherMixableAudioShouldDuck,     sizeof(value), &value);

    AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
}

- (void)updateLabels
{

if(fmod(mins,5) == 0){
 [self setAudioSessionWithDucking:YES];

    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance
                                    speechUtteranceWithString:newText];
    AVSpeechSynthesizer *synth = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];

    utterance.rate = 0.45;
    utterance.pitchMultiplier = 0.95;
    utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-GB"];
    utterance.volume = 1.0;

    [synth speakUtterance:utterance];

 [self setAudioSessionWithDucking:NO];
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to tell other apps that they may resume audio playback:

```
-(void)notifyIOSthatOtherAppsCanResumeAudioPlayback{
    NSError *err;
    [indigoAudioSession setActive: NO
                  withOptions: AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation
                        error: &err];
    if(err!=nil){
        NSLog(@"audioIsFreeNotificationForIOS ERROR: %@",err.description);
    }
}
```

If the audio you want to resume comes from your own app, you can tell it to resume playback from this delegate method:

```
- (void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didFinishSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance{
    playSomeMusic();
```

}